# How can we redact dynamic strings in Datadog traces?

Tags: python, datadog

If we do `raise RuntimeError(password)` in an endpoint handler, the password will show up in the Datadog trace. How can we tell Datadog that certain variables should be redacted?

Answer (score 0):

First we need a function that can be called in an endpoint handler that takes a string and adds it to a list of strings to redact for that trace:

```py
import json

from ddtrace import tracer


def set_redacted_str(s: str):
    root_span = tracer.current_root_span()
    assert root_span is not None
    tag_value = root_span.get_tag("redact")
    if tag_value is None:
        new_list = []
    else:
        new_list = json.loads(tag_value)
    new_list.append(s)
    root_span.set_tag_str("redact", json.dumps(new_list))
```

Now we can do

```py
def endpoint_handler(password, ...):
    set_redacted_str(password)
    ...
```

What remains is to actually do the redaction. We can do this with a custom [trace filter](https://ddtrace.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced_usage.html#trace-filtering):

```py
from ddtrace import Span
from ddtrace.filters import TraceFilter


class RedactionFilter(TraceFilter):
    def process_trace(self, trace: list[Span]) -> list[Span]:
        bad_strs = set()
        for span in trace:
            # is it ok if we just look at the one
            # where `span.parent_id is None`?
            tag = span.get_tag("redact")
            if tag is not None:
                bad_strs.update(json.loads(tag))

        for span in trace:
            for k, v in list(span.get_tags().items()):
                new_v = v
                for bs in bad_strs:
                    new_v = new_v.replace(bs, "REDACTED")
                span.set_tag_str(k, new_v)

        return trace
```